# Loop over a JSON object containing an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, object, for-loop

really hope someone can help me with this, it's driving me mad now...

I have a JSON object, with source:

```
[{"description":"General Accessories & Parts","id":"1"},{"description":"General Parts","id":"2"},{"description":"Parts","id":"3"}]
```

It's an array returned from PHP, it used to look like this:

```
$array[0]['description']="General Accessories & Parts";
$array[0]['id']="1";

$array[1]['description']="General Parts";
$array[1]['id']="2";

etc...
```

So, I put the array into my JavaScript code:

```
obj=eval(ajax.responseText);
```

Now I need to loop over the description and id for each element in the array, I did try this:

```
for(var key in obj){
    if(!obj[key].hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    alert(obj[key]['description']);
}
```

The above code that I tried just echos `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` which is the 3 objects that I know are there.

Comment: Do you have Firebug? You can inspect your eval'd object. And btw, using eval is considered evil. You should use JSON.parse() if supported by browser. If you're using jQuery or Prototype they also have api methods for this.

Comment: Did you encode the $array to be in Json format in PHP code?

Comment: @ Richard H : Yeah got firebug and inspected the object it's the same as posted above, nothing strange withit that I can see. OK will use JSON.parse(), thanks for the tip, makes sense. But not allowed to use any classes like jQuery or Prototype because it'll make the boss mad.

Comment: @ Gunner : Yeah, in the php code I did: json_encode($array);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
alert( obj[0].description );
```

and not

```
alert( obj[0]['description'] );
```

Quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/W4dwx/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, but I tried that aswell, with this I just get undefined

Comment: WOW, bookmarked that site, nice. Yeah It's working in there no problem so it must be something else in my code so you can have best answer on this.

Comment: I'm going to post another question because I have a small idea about why this is happening, something to do with closures possibly, due to the way everything's been coded.

Answer (score 0):

strange code: if(!obj[key].hasOwnProperty(key))

in your case, the key variable will iterate values 0, 1, 2

and you will ask for obj[0].hasOwnProperty(0)

Comment: Hi, I used if(!obj[key].hasOwnProperty(key)) so that it didn't itterate over anything else that could be in the object.

Comment: if(!obj[key].hasOwnProperty(key)) continue; will skip past the keys I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really duplicate your answer, but I'm pretty certain the issue is either a) in your response text (any chance we can get an alert of the exact output?) or b) in your for loop (you're iterating over an array, so it *shouldn't* have its own property):

```
var a = [{"description":"General Accessories & Parts","id":"1"},
         {"description":"General Parts","id":"2"},
         {"description":"Parts","id":"3"}];
var b = JSON.stringify(a);
eval("var c = " + b);
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  alert(c[i].description); // alert the three values you want
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I picked a best answer already but yours is good. It turns out the problem is to do with something else in my code, the for loop is actually working fine, except it gives the wrong answer due to something else.. I'm think closures and execution contexts but not really sure so I'll have to post another question with more detailed code